# How to re-start the cancelled build in teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

By mistake I cancelled the build in teamcity as it showed build hung, It was almost complete which was realized later, how to restart the cancelled build in teamcity?

Thanks in Advance,
Raj

Comment: If it's locked - restart the machine, if not - just click "Run" again

Answer (score 0):

You can also start a custom build specifying explicit revision to build ("Run" button "..." area).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to rollback changes made by this build in target environment, delete build to release VCS changes, decrease build counter and then start build this config again. at least I do so when my builds(SSDT DataBase project build and deploy with scripting DB differences at second step) fall.